# Querying helper table within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to import central banks interest rates into google sheets. The table I'm using can be found here:

```
=importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1)
```

[image]

For each items that I want from this table, I would have a function like (in this example, to fetch 1.00%):

```
=value(substitute(index(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1),2,3),",",""))
```

If I need this whole table, which consists of 12 rows (excluding header) x 4 columns, I would have 48 such formulas. It seems to me that:

- this is messy, and
- making 48 calls to the investing.com URL where one could probably suffice.

So I decided to try a different approach. In another tab of my google sheets, I call the whole table:

[image]

In my other tab, I thought to query this table (assume it is in a tab called `rates`) instead. But I don't know how. Is there a way, and if so, what is the correct way to query say:

- the first name in the table (Federal Reserve (FED))?
- the fourth interest rate in the table (-0.75%)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get 1%, try

```
=index(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1),2,3)
```

[index](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)

adapt parameters to fetch

- the first name in the table (Federal Reserve (FED)) `=index(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1),2,2)`
- or the fourth interest rate in the table (-0.75%) `=index(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1),5,3)`

To get all % per banks at once

```
=query(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1),"select Col2,Col3",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer he gave you Mike Steelson is good, but if I were you, I would make it in such a way that I could change the parameters at any time

```
=query(importhtml("https://www.investing.com/central-banks","table",1);"select Col2 WHERE (Col3='"&$A1&"')",1)
```

where A1 = 1.00% or any number entered into that cell